# Detect elements width change in angulars Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i use sly carousel for angularjs application , but its has some issues. 
One of them this case.

When carousel changes his size , or load the new data , its work with bug , so , now i have this directive , my target is 'cont' .

**I need detect , every time , if cont change his width then reload sly carousel** . (Window resize works perfectly)

```
BET5.directive('slyHorizontalRepeat', [
  '$timeout',
  function ($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

        if (scope.$last === true) {
          $timeout(function () {
            var cont = $('#frame')
            var frame = $(el[0]).parent().parent();
            var wrap = $(el[0]).parent().parent().parent();
            defaultOptions.horizontal = 1;
            var defaultControls = {
                scrollBar: wrap.find('.scrollbar') || null,
                pagesBar: wrap.find('.pages') || null,
                forward: wrap.find('.forward') || null,
                backward: wrap.find('.backward') || null,
                prev: wrap.find('.prev') || null,
                next: wrap.find('.next') || null,
                prevPage: wrap.find('.prevPage') || null,
                nextPage: wrap.find('.nextPage') || null
              };

            // Merge parts into options object for sly argument
            var options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, defaultControls, scope.$eval(attrs.slyOptions));
            var callback = scope.$eval(attrs.slyCallback) || function (cb) {
            };

            scope.$watch(cont, function (newTime) {
              // do something
            });

            $(window).on('resize', function () {
              frame.sly('reload');
              console.log('resize');
            });

            // Call Sly on frame
            frame.sly(options, callback());
          });
        }
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work...

```
scope.$watch(
  function() {return cont.width()},
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
      frame.sly('reload');
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Beside this issue , angular-sly carousel has another issue , when user open another carousel , the new one gets size from the old one ... how can i init sly in this case ?

Comment: Better create a question for this

Comment: Done 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758857/init-carousel-every-time-after-selecting